# Token been modified - AWS SNS using GCM

Tags: amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging, boto, amazon-sns

We're using python boto to create endpoint on AWS SNS - used for Push Notification.

We use the following call to create the endpoint for a specific device:

```
sns_conn.create_platform_endpoint(app_arn, token, user_data)
```

Where the token is the device-token.

After this call, we take a look @ the AWS SNS console.

When using APNS/APNS_SANDBOX - in the 'Token' column of our APN application, we see the same device-token as we supplied.

When using GCM - in the 'Token' column of our GCM application, we see a different token than what we have supplied.

strange.

We found no documentation on that.

It seems the token is being encrypted or manipulated somehow (not by us).

Anyone knows why this token is different?

Comment: What happens if you do a ``get_endpoint_attributes`` on the endpoint ARN you have created?  Does the token look modified or is it the same as you provided?

Comment: How does the 'Token' column for GCM look like? What's its length?

Comment: @eran - same length, 164 characters. same format but different.

Comment: @garnaat - yes. the token inside the endpoint attributes is the same as given but it is different than the one displayed in the sns application's endpoints table. strange.

Comment: @Amit Talmor I got the same error Anybody know why?